# use "this" in hyperlink onclick

Tags: jquery, html, events

Html code :

```
<a id='link1' href='#' name='john' >test</a>
<br/><br/>
<a id='link2' href='#' name='john' onclick="showName();">test</a>
<br/><br/>
<a id='link3' href='#' name='smith' onclick="showName();">test</a>
```

JScript code :

```
$(function()
  {
      $('#link1').on('click', function(){
          alert($(this).attr('name'));
      });
  }
)

function showName()
{
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
}
```

And the fiddle of it :
http://jsfiddle.net/eS7Mv/7/

Why does the second and third links don't work ?
BTW, I need to use a named function for some reasons.
So I know that :

```
 $('a').on('click', function(){
          alert($(this).attr('name'));
      });
```

Or

```
 $('.TargetClass').on('click', function(){
          alert($(this).attr('name'));
      });
```

Will somehow solve the problem but I do need to work with named functions and access hyperlink attributes.

---

### **Update: Thanks to all who contributed to this thread. I can't thank you enough. I appreciate all of them but since there are multiple correct answers at the same time I don't know how to mark all of these responses as an answer at the same time.**

Comment: First off all they share a common `id` which is invalid, they should be unique..

Comment: you are binding click event inline for these tags which will call handler before jQuery one. And your are not passing element as argument. So what are you looking for? Here maybe: http://jsfiddle.net/eS7Mv/14/

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thank you I have updated that issue but they were not the source of the problem.

Comment: `onclick="showName(this);"` -- or look at `e.target`

Comment: Check out this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eS7Mv/8/)...is this how you want it?

Comment: @S.C. That's why I wrote *First Of All*, as if that was an answer, I would've posted :)

Comment: @BradChristie what is e ? e should be the parameter for showName ?

Comment: @S.C.: Yes, argument within method call.

Comment: @S.C.: Check out my answer, because I knew you were looking for e.target

Comment: @Butterfruit You didn't use the named function.

Answer (score 3):

use this code

html code

```
<a id='link1' href='#' name='john' >test</a><br/><br/>
<a id='link2' href='#' name='john' onclick="showName(this);">test</a><br/><br/>
<a id='link3' href='#'name='smith'onclick="showName(this);">test</a>
```

jquery code is

```
 function showName(obj)
{
alert($(obj).attr('name'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

Demo Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eS7Mv/18/

```
<a id='link1' href='#' name='john' >test</a>
<br/><br/>
<a id='link2' href='#' name='john' onclick="showName(this);">test</a>
<br/><br/>
<a id='link3' href='#' name='smith' onclick="showName(this);">test</a>
<script>
    function showName(element)
{
    alert($(element).attr('name'));
}
</script>
```

By calling `showName(this)` you are passing the current element to the function.

**Edit 2**

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eS7Mv/22/

Comment: Why showName function should be here ? Why it doesn't work when being moved to script section ?

Comment: i have placed a updated fiddle and moved the function to script section.

Answer (score 1):

second and third link should not work because in your javascript function "this" specifies current object so at that time javascript can't find current object so you must have to pass "this" in function argument..

Answer (score 1):

just see the fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eS7Mv/8/)

you should pass a parameter this and then use this parameter inside of function

```
function showName(pthis)
{
    alert($(pthis).attr('name'));
}

<a id='link3' href='#' name='smith' onclick="showName(this);">test</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

html

```
<a id='link3' href='#' name='smith' onclick="showName(this);">test</a>
```

javascript

```
function showName(obj)
{
    alert(obj.name);
   //or
   alert($(obj).attr('name'));
}
```

Comment: I was very attracted by **obj.name** since I never seen that way before. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated `working code` => http://jsfiddle.net/eS7Mv/13/

**You need to keep some common property between all elements that will then be accessed by JQuery and you can bind events to those then**

**As per your comment, this is how you can use named functions. Let me know if I can help you with more code.**

```
$(function()
  {
      $('.click').on('click', showName );
  }
)

function showName()
{
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
   // alert("Hello World");
}
```

**This is the updated fiddle** => http://jsfiddle.net/eS7Mv/26/

Comment: I have to use named function.

Comment: @S.C. I am updating my answer that will help you use named functions. I hope you require something like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of jQuery, the 'this' in a function bound like this will:

> If the function being invoked was created using Function.bind(), this
>   will be the first argument that was passed to .bind() at the time the
>   function was created.
>
> http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/

Your other inline functions don't work, as the 'this' is the current context of execution (the window I think).

If you really need to use named functions, could you do this:

```
$(function()
  {
      $('#link1').on('click', function(){
          showName($(this));
      });
  }
)

function showName(clickedLink)
{
    alert(clickedLink.attr('name'));
}
```

Small fiddle illustrating some of this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4axju/1/

Answer (score -1):

If all your tags are starting with `link`, then you can do like this

```
  $('[id^=link]').on('click', function(){
          alert($(this).attr('name'));
      });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/eS7Mv/9/)**

Answer (score -1):

### Solution | [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eS7Mv/24/)

You are looking for `e.target.node`, so:

```
$('body').on('click', function(e){
    alert(e.target.name);    
});
```

Simplify your life.

Also, if you don't want it to run for the entire `body`, then you can also do:

```
$('#link1, #link2, #link3').on('click', function(e){
```

The reason you previous code didn't work was because of the rules. In jQuery docs, it is stated that "If the function being invoked was created using Function.bind(), `this` will be the first argument that was passed to .bind() at the time the function was created." In your case, it went undefined I think.

Using the console feature in Chrome, I turned out to be right. Have a look at this screenshot and try to understand what's happening. Do you see what you were doing wrong?

[image]
When events are raised, for instance a click event, they carry important information and references around with them. In a click event, the event object has a reference to target. Using this, you can get the id of the element that raised the event.

Answer (score -1):

The `onclick` attribute only works, when the JS code is located before this html tag, or the specified function will not be found.

In your example, this works: http://jsfiddle.net/eS7Mv/20/

But jQuery is the better way to go for you, e.g.:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Comment: So for that we can use `.ready()` so anyways this doesn't answer his question

Comment: Didn't downvoted but no, it doesn't answer his question, placing the code below `a` won't work as well